# Lenovo Tab 4 10 Plus connect to wired network

Tags: lenovo

I have bought Lenovo Tab 4 10 Plus unit recently. It replaced my laptop perfectly but one, I need to connect to a server on a local closed wired network. I tried to connect using a USB C Hub with Ethernet port. The hub can support usb flash disk but not with ethernet.

I contacted Lenovo support, they said it does not support ethernet and the USB is a USB 2.0 only for data and charging.

Any idea on how can I connect to a local closed wired network? Its okay to purchase a small device that can easy to bring.

TIA

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Purchase a small wireless access point and connect that to LAN, then connect wirelessly to the WAP.